# dual-end powered ballast bypass with fixture that has a built in switch

Tags: ballast, bypass

I am attempting to do a ballast bypass for LED tube lights. The LED bulbs are dual-end powered with just one bulb per fixture.

The pictures showed the wires I have at the ballast. The black wire on the left is from the switch, which is from the black power line.

The directions tell me to connect the 2 red wires from the right to the black wire.  Then connect the blue and the white to the white line coming into the fixture.
[image]
My question is: Does the black wire from the switch go back to the black power line with the two red wires or to the white wire?  Im puzzled because it Seems the black wire, that comes from the black power line should go back to black, not white.

Comment: I think the instructions are correct, based on the diagram on the ballast.  Basically, you are wiring out the ballast as if it was not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what the instructions call "the white wire coming into the fixture" is not in the picture. Make sure you know which one it is. It comes in with a black wire that goes to the switch. There's a **different** black wire that comes out of the switch and goes to the ballast; that's the black wire in the picture.

So just follow the directions; don't overthink it.

Cut all five wires off of the ballast.

Connect the black wire that you just cut to the two red wires that you just cut. Don't do anything else with black wires or red wires.

Connect the white wire coming into the fixture to the white wire that you just cut (it's almost certainly already connected) and to the blue wire that you just cut. Don't do anything else with white wires or the blue wire.

Close up the fixture. You're done.

Comment: If the incoming white wire isn't connected to the white wire we see here, the old fixture would not have worked, so that's overcomplicating that aspect.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- indeed; but the paraphrased instructions say "connect the blue and the white to the white line coming into the fixture", so that needed to be mentioned. I've edited the answer to make it clearer.